# How to update all values in a Deedle frame?

Tags: c#, deedle

I want to replace all values in a deedle Frame / Series;
Example, I want to replace all -1 by 0.

I could not find a way to do it. in F#, there seem to be a mapValue function, but can't find equivalent in C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is also a `Select` method on the entire `Frame<R, C>` type so you should be able to write something like this (I have not tested this though):

```
var res = df.Select((int row, string col, double v) => v == -1 ? 0 : v);
```

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, found a snippet that does the job:

```
 void cleanupDF(Frame<int, string> df) {
    foreach(string c in new string[] {"col1","col2" }) {
        var relabeled = df.Columns[c].Select(kvp => ((int)kvp.Value ==- 1 ? 0 : (int)kvp.Value));
        df.ReplaceColumn(c, relabeled);
    }
}
```